# Integration by subtitution :

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am having problem in solving the integration:
$$\int  \frac{e^x (x+1)}{\cos^2 (x e^x)} dx.$$ Please help

Comment: Substitute $u=xe^x$.

Comment: @zz20s  yes but it is (cos (x e^x)) ^2. It means cos has power 2.

Comment: Now I am confused. The most edit could either mean $\int  \frac{e^x (x+1)}{(\cos^2 x e^x)} dx$ or $\int  \frac{e^x (x+1)}{\cos ((x e^x)^2)} dx$. From the most recent edit, it looks like the former. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @zz20s  the first one is the correct one!

Comment: Okay. Please take a look at either one of the two answers. If you need more help, please comment.

Comment: In the future please include in your Question details of what you tried.  Saying "I am having problem" does not give your Readers enough information.  If, as the title suggests, you tried "substitution", be specific in the body of the Question as to what you tried and what difficulty you encountered.

Comment: Ok. I will look after it from my next questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $xe^x=u$ and  and $\mathrm du=(xe^x+e^x) \mathrm dx=e^x(x+1) \mathrm dx$ (the derivative follows from the product rule). This gives

$$\int \sec^2 u \mathrm du=\tan u+C=\tan (xe^x)+C.$$

EDIT: Fixed to account for edit in question.

Comment: Question has been edited

Comment: But the answer is only tan(x e^x)+c

Comment: Can you plz show me how du =e^x(x+1)dx

Comment: This results from the product rule, which says $(wv)'=wv'+w'v$. Now, let $w=e^x$ and $v=x$. Then, $w'=e^x$ and $v'=1$. EDIT: I changed the $u$ to $w$ since I had already used $u$ as a variable.

Comment: Plz show me how du=e^x (x+1)

Comment: If $u=xe^x$, then $\frac{du}{dx}=e^x+xe^x.$ For ease of notation, multiply $dx$ to the other side as though you were multiplying fractions. Thus, $du=(e^x+xe^x)dx$ Essentially, I defined $u$, differentiated both sides, and then multiplied $dx$ over.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $(\cos(xe^x))^2=\cos^2(xe^x)$, so one should get  $$\int \frac{e^x(x+1)}{(\cos(xe^x))^2}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{d(xe^x)}{\cos^2(xe^x)}$$
$$=\int \sec^2(xe^x)d(xe^x)$$
$$=\color{red}{\tan(xe^x)+C}$$